# Redis cache configuration in Django using django-environ

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, environ

Hereis the relevant part of my `settings.py`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': env.str("REDIS_URI"),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'DB': 1,
            'SOCKET_TIMEOUT': 5,
            'SOCKET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT': 5,
            'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'redis.BlockingConnectionPool',
            'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS_KWARGS': {
                'max_connections': 50,
                'timeout': 20},
            'PICKLE_VERSION': -1,
        },
    },
}
```

I'm moving the above configruation to django-environ:

```
env REDIS_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1client_class=redis_cache.RedisCache&default_timeout=360
```

How can I add the connection URL from `REDIS_URL` to Django's `DATABASES`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are missing a `?` in the URL parameters:

```
REDIS_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=redis_cache.RedisCache&default_timeout=360
```

Second, it is all described [in the docs](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In your case:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': env.cache()  # default = 'CACHE_URL' environmennt variable
}
```

`CACHE_URL` needs to be set as environment variable.

```
export CACHE_URL=rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=redis_cache.RedisCache&default_timeout=360
```

If you insist on using `REDIS_URL` you can do the following:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': env.cache('REDIS_URL')
}
```

Other options can be added using URL parameters.